# Non English 3d Text with Python

Tags: python, scripting, text-object

I am trying to create 3d text object using python. The text has non english letters and the default 3d text font doesn't have these letters. I can use another font file that supports the entire character set. But I want to share the script with other users and don't want to hard-code the file name (or path, the users might have different OS or they may not have the font file).

What is the best way to create this script? Is there a way to get from the script the default system font, which would support all the characters?

Comment: it is possible to use a .svg file and use it instead of text.

Comment: Actually, the text will be dynamically created from within the script.